# In auth0, are client ids unique to a given app, or to a given instance of an app running on a device?

Tags: authentication, auth0, clientid

I'm reading a tutorial on Auth0 at this link: https://auth0.com/docs/getting-started/the-basics

It says "Each application is assigned a Client ID upon creation". When it says "application" does it mean the app in general, or an instance of the app running on a given device? In other words, if my friend and I are running the same app on out respective devices, is the app given a client id when it's created, say "id123", and the client id is "id123" for the instances of the app running on both of our devices, or would my instance be given one client id, and my friend's another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says "Each application is assigned a Client ID upon creation". When it says "application" does it mean the app in general, or an instance of the app running on a given device?

It means under the Application tab, the client ID associated with each app in there, not on any given device. I hope this clarifies things!